# Publish TeamCity artifacts. How to get Build IDs

Tags: teamcity, integration, continuous

I´ve created a Artifact path in TeamCity like this:

`src\MyBuild\bin\Release\* => MyBuild.zip`

Now I want to publish this created artifact through a download link:

```
http://localhost:8080/repository/downloadAll/BUILD_TYPE_ID/BUILD_ID:id?showAll=true
```

...But where I can get the `BUILD_TYPE_ID` and the `BUILD_ID`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts) shows several different ways of getting to artifacts that might be easier.

To help you along though, I believe **BUILD_ID** is the internal ID of a particular build but unfortunately I don't know how to get  it. I do know though that you can substitute ".lastSuccessful" to get the last successful build. **BUILD_TYPE_ID** is the ID of the project you want artifacts for. You can find it by going to your team city page and clicking on that project. You should see a URL that looks like

> `http://yourteamcity:8080/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt1&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv`

See the "buildTypeId=bt1"? That bt1 is the BUILD_TYPE_ID (it is likely to be something other than bt1 on your machine).

#### An example

We use the following URL pattern to get at artifacts.

> `http://yourteamcity:8080/repository/downloadAll/BUILD_TYPE_ID/BUILD_NUMBER`

It still uses the BUILD_TYPE_ID, but it uses BUILD_NUMBER instead of BUILD_ID. BUILD_NUMBER is visible on the TeamCity project page.

So for us an example link to get build number 312.4 would look as follows -

> `http://yourteamcity:8080/repository/downloadAll/bt1/312.4`

Your numbering scheme may be very different.